# How to use an array (inside a javascript script) to create a SVG Polygon chart with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts, polygon

I'm having a syntaxic headache. I've tried several tutorials, none working. And I don't get the logics. Please could you give my smile back? :D

I'm drawing a polygon with D3js.

This works perfectly =>

```
svg.append('polygon')
    .attr("points", "50,0, 89,19, 100,61, 72,94, 28,94")
    .attr("class", "radar-area");
```

But here I have to write manually the points (that are continuously moving...)

I collect these points in an array like this:

```
    var Data = [
        {"x":50,"y":0},
        {"x":89,"y":19},
        {"x":100,"y":61},
        {"x":72,"y":94},
        {"x":28,"y":94},
    ];
```

How can I correctly use this array "Data" to set the points of the polygon?

Many thanks for the help!

Whole code:

PHP document:

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    require('view/resources/radar_chart.php');
    $radar_chart = ob_get_clean();
    ?>
/*and a bit further:*/
    <div class="radarchart"><?= $radar_chart ?></div>
```

JS script (the resource required) :

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var margin = {top:10, right:10, bottom:10, left:10},
            width = 120 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var svg = d3.select('.radarchart')
        .append('svg');
    svg.attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right);
    svg.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    var Data = [
        {"x":50,"y":0},
        {"x":89,"y":19},
        {"x":100,"y":61},
        {"x":72,"y":94},
        {"x":28,"y":94},
    ];
    /*In fact, this array is filled by variables, but useless to complexify with that here, so I replaced with figures*/

svg.append('polygon')
    .attr("points", ""/*How do I get the points from "Data" ?*/)
    .attr("class", "radar-area");

</script>
```

And the class "radar-area" in CSS file :

```
.radar-area{
    fill: var(--theme-pink);
}
```

Comment: Try `svg.append('polygon').attr("points", `${Data[0].x},${Data[0].y} ${Data[1].x},${Data[1].y} ...etc`

Comment: `.attr("points", Data.map(p => p.x+","+p.y).join(" "))`

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that doesn't work, "unexpected token {" pointing on the { after the first $ sign of your proposition. But thanks, worthed the try^^ (edit: was answering to enxaneta - I'm gonna try right now your line, Thomas)

Comment: thanks too! But doesn't work either ^^ (unexpected token "." on the line of your proposal)

Comment: OK had to change the name of the array, seems he disliked "Data"^^ Finally your help is perfect, Thomas, it works 100% now! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor change, because you can use ES desctructuring

Also note **,** or *spaces* (or a mix) are both fine as separator

```js
var Data = [
        {"x":50,"y":0},
        {"x":89,"y":19},
        {"x":100,"y":61},
        {"x":72,"y":94},
        {"x":28,"y":94},
    ];
var points = Data.map(({x,y}) => x+","+y).join(",");

document.body.append(points)
```